# Wants to get value from Xml Attribute using XSLT

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot, xslt

```
<Document1>
    <DocumentRequest Application="Standard">
        <Doc Format="Pdf">
        <Variable Name="CUST" Value = "Aman" Type="String/>
        <Variable Name="DPID" Value = "7488493" Type="String/>
        <Variable Name="NA Number" Value = "Aman" Type="String/>
        <Variable Name="DELTA" Value = "Test" Type="String/>
        </Doc>
    </DocumentRequest>
</Document1>
```

This is my XML I want to get the value of the Name attribute from Variable Tag and assign it to different variables. the output should be like -

```
{
"var1":"Aman",
"var2":"7488493",
"var3":"Aman",
"var4":"Test",
}
```

I want to write XSLT to do this. How can I write XSLT and assign these values?

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: What kind of result format is that? You say you want to "assign to different variables". In which language?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only have one level of `Variable`s, you can use this simple XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />      
  <xsl:template match="/Document1/DocumentRequest/Doc[@Format='Pdf']">
    <xsl:text>{&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="Variable">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('  &quot;var',position(),'&quot;:&quot;',@Value,'&quot;')" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>,&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
{
  "var1":"Aman",
  "var2":"7488493",
  "var3":"Aman",
  "var4":"Test"
}
```

The above code matches the specified `Doc` element and then iterates over all `Variable` elements. Because the stylesheet is XSLT version 1.0, it should be runnable in Java's XSLT processor without further complications.
I added an `xsl-if`-clause to omit the comma after the last element to make it more JSON like.